# Does memorizing a copyrighted work create a copy?

Tags: copyright, is-x-legal

There's a lot of hubub recently about ML models memorizing their training data, and the copyright implications of that.

How did this used to work before fancy technology was brought into it? If I buy a book of poetry at the store, I have one copy. If I memorize it, now there physically *must* be a copy in my head, right? I can sell the book and still have the poems. If I go around teaching people all the poems until they too have memorized them (but not in the context of a public performance), aren't I committing copyright infringement and making a bunch of unauthorized copies in people's heads?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151103/discussion-on-question-by-interfect-does-memorizing-a-copyrighted-work-create-a); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 17):

Memorizing a work is not copyright infringement.

Infringement requires doing something that is an exclusive right of the copyright owner.

One of the exclusive rights of a copyright owner is the right to make a "copy" or "reproduction." This concept is defined to various degrees of precision, depending on the jurisdiction, but for one example, in the U.S., "copies" are defined as:

> material objects, other than phonorecords, in which a work is fixed by any method now known or later developed, and from which the work can be perceived, reproduced, or otherwise communicated, either directly or with the aid of a machine or device.

Many jurisdictions, and the Berne Convention itself, do not define "reproduction" or "copy." But the WIPO *Guide to the Copyright and Related Rights Treaties Administered by WIPO and Glossary of Copyright and Related Rights Terms* (2003) at 55 says:

> The text of the Berne Convention does not contain any complete and explicit definition of “reproduction”. Certain elements of the concept of reproduction may, however, be identified in it.  A good example is the clarification offered in Article 9(3) [sound or visual recordings deemed to be reproductions] . . . which makes it obvious that it is not a condition that, on the basis of the reproduction, the copy of the work be directly perceivable; it is sufficient if the reproduced work may be made perceivable through appropriate equipment.

Memorization is not one of the exclusive rights held by a copyright owner, and memorization does not result in a "copy" as defined in the U.S., nor in any jurisdiction's conception of a "reproduction."

Comment: But I guess it would still be one if you replayed that memory. So if you memorize say a music score, playing it back in public would still be copyright infringement.

Comment: I don't think it's as easy as in this answer. Digital copies on computer hard drives somehow do satisfy the definition, although the "physical" substance of the copy is rather intangible (the _state_ of electromagnetic charge of the disk surface/cells). The copy in a human brain is intangible likewise. The principal difference is that brains can't be read as easy.

Comment: @Greendrake The brain is not a physical object from which memories can be perceived, reproduced, or communicated by anyone other than the owner. Transcribing a book into a unique language unknown to anyone but the person who invented is not generating a copy, nor is creating a photocopy of a book which turns out to be illegibly smudged. A physical object is not a copy if no person or machine can perceive that it is, in fact, a copy. It's not the "intangibility" of bits or memories that differentiate the copyright issue, it's the ability to decode them.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie That seems quite incorrect. Are you getting this from a legal authority, or is it mostly just a guess?

Comment: @bdb484 9th Circuit Court:  "the material object must, in some manner, take on the physical aspects of the protected work such that the “copy” of the work may be perceived by an observer". My examples are cases where it is *impossible* for the "work" to perceived as such by an observer. I don't see how you could be guilty of copyright infringement if no one can perceive that your work is, in fact, a copy of another.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie, I agree with everything you are saying, except:  "*I don't see how you could be guilty of copyright infringement if no one can perceive that your work is, in fact, a copy of another.*"  Perception in this case is irrelevant.  If you copy and distribute the work of another person the recipent's knowledge (or lack thereof) that it is a copy doesn't alter the fact that you may have violated a copyright in creating it.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie But can you see where you've tweaked the test? You're treating it as a requirement that the work can be perceived *as a copy*; the law only requires that it can be perceived, period. Making the copy while sitting alone on the dark side of the Moon doesn't protect you.

Comment: You're of course right that you won't be *found* guilty of copyright infringement. But that's only because you can't get caught. Legally, you have still infringed copyright.

Comment: @bdb484 I don't think there's any such thing as "attempted copyright infringement" where you intended to copy a work, but wind up producing something that is not in any way, shape or form a copy of the original. If you put a copyrighted book in a photocopier but don't have any ink, the blank pages that come out are surely not infringing copyright no matter what your intent was - you haven't actually made a copy.

Comment: I agree with that, but I don't see it as supporting any of your previous statements. If you're unsuccessful in making a copy, you haven't made a copy, even if the whole world knows you tried. If you're successful in making a copy (even in a form that others don't recognize), you've made a copy, even if no one knows.

Comment: The issue I have with "the copy of the work be directly perceivable" is " in which a work is fixed by any method now known or later developed, and from which the work can be perceived, reproduced, or otherwise communicated, either directly or with the aid of a machine or device" which suggests that something that isn't copyright infringement *now* such as memorization could be at a later date if a machine or device is later developed to perceive it (for instance, a mind reading device).

Comment: And thinking about what I said, I don't think the "work is fixed by any method now known or later developed" exempts this on the grounds that "later developed" is referring only to the fixing method, because the fixing method is already known now (memorization techniques) and nothing is said about whether the retrieval mechanism must presently exist.  If it *did* exclude mechanisms not yet existing I would imagine that would be a pretty big loophole as you could develop the means to record knowing the means to play back would be developed later, then copy everything you can before developing t

Comment: What about the OP's scenario where they teach the memorized poems to others? If they do this privately, it's not a "public performance".

Comment: @Barmar: Further, suppose that many people who have heard a poem, song, or other piece of verse teach it to others, sometimes with deliberate or accidental embellishments.  If one or more people transcribe the work, what would be the copyright status of present or future oral-tradition variants?

Comment: @supercat Of course, these are just academic questions. In practice, passing things on orally doesn't have enough volume for anyone to actually prosecute. This is why copyright protection only applies to *public* performances, since they can reach mass audiences.

Comment: @Barmar: The question isn't just academic.  It's not uncommon for songs--especially parody songs--to come into existence through oral tradition.  Having songs transcribed into a fixed medium while someone remembers them is desirable, but creates problems if people who would consider transcribing it have no way of knowing what transcriptions, if any, might already exist, and who if anyone might own them.

Comment: @Barmar: As a concrete example, a variation of the song "Good morning to all" with lyrics starting "Happy birthday to you" appears to have become widespread via oral tradition well before any publication of the song with those lyrics.  If the heirs and copyright holders of a song publish a version they discovered via oral tradition, would they have any right to claim ownership over performance rights for the revised version after the copyright on the original lapses?

Comment: @Jen So does my-brain-with-a-poem-in-it not count as a copy under the U.S. definition because my brain is not a "material object"? Or because the process of memorization does not count as "fixing"? Or becuse the work can't be communicated from my brain (except by me)? Or for some other reason?

Answer (score -6):

### The issue with AI training is they didn’t buy the book of poetry

If you change your analogy to printing out a book of poetry you scraped from the internet and then memorising it, it is the print out that is the copyright infringement, not the memorisation.

Comment: An additional issue is that the copy/derivative work which was created, the AI model, to create further derivative works when the AI model is used to create something else (e.g., the response from ChatGPT). For LLMs, it's been shown that they can, under some conditions, recreate the text that was used to train them, or substantial portions of that text. That latter fact makes it quite clear that the AI model is, in fact, a derivative work "from which the work can be perceived, reproduced, or otherwise communicated, either directly or with the aid of a machine or device."

Comment: I don't know if the headline is really a useful analogy.  Anyone can go to a library and start memorizing books without buying anything.  The legal problem, both for the human who memorizes physical library books and the AI trained on the digital library which is the internet, is in the later reproduction of the memorized/trained material.  IMO, whether or not the human or AI trainer owns a copy of the original may not be particularly relevant.

Comment: I believe that there certainly are at least some cases where a model is trained on a legitimately obtained copy of some works (i.e. that they *did* "buy the book of poetry"), but without a permission or license to make further copies, and the question should be treated in the context of this "cleaner" scenario, where you do not have an infringement already before the "memorization" is even attempted.

Comment: The "scraping from the internet" also involves making a copy, and is infringing unless it's covered by some exemption such as fair use.

Comment: Downvoting. The fact that they didn't buy it is completely irrelevant to the question; buying it wouldn't give them a right to copy it.

Comment: @josh3736 AFAIK Internet libraries are illegal (unless authorized by the copyright holder) - the right to lend a copy only applies to physical copies (for some reason).